# Mechanism to email log entries from log4j output

Tags: java, logging, jakarta-ee, log4j, java-ee-6

Have had some trouble with log4j's SMTPAppender not emailing INFO log entries, I think I've solved that.  But now I'm curious if that's the best solution.  I'm very frequently emailing based on output of different logfiles.  Is there a better solution than SMTPAppender to email?  I'd rather not harm performance of my app and the emailing happen asynchronously.  And it'd be nice to maybe even email every 5 minutes with the accumulated log entries instead of one at a time as they happen.

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of SMTPAppender is to notify you about critical events promptly or at least when N number of the events had occured, that is why by default only ERROR logs are mailed out. There is also property cb of type CyclicBuffer declared on the SMTPAppender type, use it to control the number of collected log statement before they are sent. If the application is running in Linux environment, it be more appropriate to use CRON to send those log statements every 5 minutes. TaskScheduler may help to achive the same on Windows platform.

Comment: what command can I run in a linux cron to send log statements where I'm ONLY sent the log entries that I haven't seen yet?

Comment: 1.setup log4j to write logs into file (use RollingFileAppender)
2.create cronjob
 2.1 check if log file exists
 2.2 copy current log file to [somename]
 2.3 use mail to send the copy
 2.4 rename/delete original log